# Passing an [out] array to C++ function

Tags: c++, arrays, c++-cli, managed-c++, out-parameters

I have a C++\CLI managed class method that takes an out array. I want to pass this out array to the underlying C++ function that takes a vector< char >&. This C++ functions fills the array with values.

```
bool MyLib::GetBits([Out] array<unsigned char>^ %bits)
{
  MyCppClass->GetBits(bits); // ????  
  // ERROR: C2664: cannot convert from 'cli::array<Type> ^' to 'std::vector<_Ty> &'
}

'GetBits' is declared as MyCppClass::GetBits(vector<char> &bits);
```

Comment: And... How you want to automatically convert ref C++/CLI class to C++ class? Anyway, look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846880/convert-systemarray-to-stdvector

Comment: I was thinking if there something similar to msclr::interop::marshal_as<> that I can use here.

Answer (score 0):

Have you any reason to expect that `array<unsigned char>^ %bits` can be converted to `vector<char> &bits`?

You can try to modify `MyCppClass`, adding a member that returns a reference to a static vector. In GetBits you can clear it, and iterate through bits adding the chars to it. You may also find [Marshaling in C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384865.aspx) useful.