# CPP: Convert unsigned char* to std::vector<unsigned char>

Tags: c++, vector, unsigned-char

I have an array of unsigned chars ( `unsigned char *`), how can I convert it to a `vector` of unsigned chars? ( `std::vector<unsigned char>` )?

Comment: do you the size of your array? also check ouit this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33654056/stdarray-or-stdvector-from-pointer

Comment: Can you please attach your code?

Comment: `vector<unsigned char> vec(array, array + size);` as already said this copies the array to the vector not converts it.

Comment: @anastaciu The answer is the same regardless of type, and an array's name decays into a pointer to its first element meaning that is the same too. The difference here is that the size will have to be known/supplied differently, assuming the underlying array is dynamic.

Comment: If the size is not known, then it can't be done.

Comment: Pointer to the array is groovy, that gives us the starting point, but where is the end? How long is the array? Can't do much safely without knowing where to stop copying.

Comment: @john Yeah, there's no way for a `vector` to take over ownership of an existing buffer, but "conversion" in C++ is widely understood to mean creating a new object anyway, so it's no problem.